# Laravel Route to ancor tag within page

Tags: laravel, routes, anchor

I have a laravel route defined as follows:

```
Route::get('/services', [\App\Http\Controllers\MiscController::class,'services'])->name('services');
```

which directs to the "clean" URL: "my-domain-name/services", as it should.

When I try to direct the link like below to a specific tag on the 'service' page, as per below:

```
{{route('services')}}/#cms
```

I get the full URL / path : my-domain-name/public/services#cms which is obviously wrong

I'm still a LARAVEL newbie so I might have forgotten something in the .ENV file ?
Many thanks,
JMB

Is there a way around this to direct the link /route to a specific anchor tag in a blade template ...?

Comment: Are you using php artisan serve as webserver on your local machine?

Comment: Have you set `APP_URL` value in `.env` file?

Comment: luukd: Yes I am using the artisan serve command locally to launch the app ;
Tpojka: yes I have set the APP_URL value to the live URL

What would the inmpact of either be ?

I forgot to mention that I saw the described behaviour when running the app live, haven't checked if it does so also locally ...

Comment: @user2955335 try clearing the routes cache

Comment: done, thanks but no changes ...

Comment: _I get the full URL / path : my-domain-name/public/services#cms which is obviously wrong_ - What was your expected output?

Comment: HI 
I was expecting a clean(...) url such as maybe my-domain-name/services#cms which would NOT show the entire path as opposed to the Laravel route....